# ProgressBar not updating in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, synchronized, android-progressbar

I have a ProgressBar in my app that represent a static value, the value is got from server.

My code in Fragment is in onCreateView, follows:

```
public class AgeFragment extends Fragment {

List<TableStatsCache> tableStatsCacheList;
String place,partial1,partial2, partial3, partial4, partial5, partial6;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    TextView placeTextView;
    TextView partial1TextView, partial2TextView, partial3TextView, partial4TextView, partial5TextView, partial6TextView;
    ProgressBar bar1ProgressBar, bar2ProgressBar, bar3ProgressBar, bar4ProgressBar, bar5ProgressBar, bar6ProgressBar;


    readTableStatsCache();

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_age, container, false);



    placeTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.placeTextView);

    partial1TextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.partial1TextView);
    partial2TextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.partial2TextView);
    partial3TextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.partial3TextView);
    partial4TextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.partial4TextView);
    partial5TextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.partial5TextView);
    partial6TextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.partial6TextView);
    bar1ProgressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bar1ProgressBar);
    bar2ProgressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bar2ProgressBar);
    bar3ProgressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bar3ProgressBar);
    bar4ProgressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bar4ProgressBar);
    bar5ProgressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bar5ProgressBar);
    bar6ProgressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.bar6ProgressBar);


    placeTextView.setText(place);
    partial1TextView.setText(partial1+"%");
    partial2TextView.setText(partial2+"%");
    partial3TextView.setText(partial3+"%");
    partial4TextView.setText(partial4+"%");
    partial5TextView.setText(partial5+"%");
    partial6TextView.setText(partial6+"%");

    bar1ProgressBar.setProgress(Math.round(Float.valueOf(partial1)));   
    bar2ProgressBar.setProgress(Math.round(Float.valueOf(partial2)));
    bar3ProgressBar.setProgress(Math.round(Float.valueOf(partial3)));
    bar4ProgressBar.setProgress(Math.round(Float.valueOf(partial4)));
    bar5ProgressBar.setProgress(Math.round(Float.valueOf(partial5)));
    bar6ProgressBar.setProgress(Math.round(Float.valueOf(partial6)));



    return rootView;
}



public void readTableStatsCache(){

    DatabaseHandlerTableStatsCache db_read = new DatabaseHandlerTableStatsCache(CallFragment.context);

    tableStatsCacheList = db_read.getAllLines();       

    for (TableStatsCache cn : tableStatsCacheList) {

        place = cn.getPlace();
        partial1 = cn.getPartial1();
        partial2 = cn.getPartial2();
        partial3 = cn.getPartial3();
        partial4 = cn.getPartial4();
        partial5 = cn.getPartial5();
        partial6 = cn.getPartial6();

    }
    }
}
```

This fragment show the ProgressBar correct when is created, but when my FragmentActivity reload the Fragment the ProgressBar is not updated.
Only the TextView is updated.

For reload a fragment, i have this in FragmentActivity:

```
    viewPager.removeAllViews();     
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

I think that a problem can be because the method "setProgress" is synchronized.

How i release the old thread to a new thread can run the method?

Comment: Could you post more code --- the entire fragment? Also, are you updating the fragment from a new thread?

Comment: Hi @Adryan did you issue get solved? If it is ,can tell what is the solution for it?

Answer (score 1):

I know I am very late to answer this question. May be you have solved this problem,but it may be helpful for the person who ran into a similar problem in future. I was also facing a similar kind of problem. In my case, the `progressbar.setProgress(someStaticValue);` was not working inside fragment which was in viewPager. I was **adding a new Fragment** when the viewPager was showing the **last page**. The data was coming from the server and after doing some calculation I need to display the progress status. My fragment was containing 4 progressBar and some textViews and all should be updated with **someStaticValue**. For the first time the progress bar was updating successfully,but after adding one MoreFragment it was not able to update the progress status of the progressbar, although the TextViews are getting updated. I did a lot of research but couldn't find the proper solution of it. Then I saw your post,you gave a hint that the problem may be, due to the **synchronized** nature of `setProgress()`.So I tried to call the setProgress() in a new Thread but the value should be updated on the mainThread. For this purpose I have used [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) . Here is how I updated my progress bar.

```
new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mScienceProgressBar.setProgress(scienceScore);
            }
        });
```

Here the updating action will be performed on a **different thread** but the updating will be reflected in the **mainThread.**

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how you get the value from server but I think that problem is with your static value. It doesnt refresh and progress on the bar doesnt change. How you retreive value from server?

Comment: The same value is used in the TextView, and the TextView update correctly. So, the problem is not with value.